# Trying to access map from function to use in scrollview

Tags: javascript, react-native

When a textInput value is changed (onChangeText), the method below is run. I want the expected values to be returned in the scroll view, but I keep getting "undefined is not an object", and the filterMap variable is not found. Obviously, it's a scope issue.
Should I be using a setState()? I tried updating a setState hook with filterMap and returning that hook in the scrollview, but nothing displayed.

error:
`undefined is not an object`

code:

```
const filterTags = text => {
  let current = text;
  if (current.length > 0) {
    tags.filter(function(tag) {
      if (tag.startsWith(text)) {
        let filterMap = tag.map(i => (
          <View>
            <Text>{i}</Text>
          </View>
        ));
        return filterMap;
      } else {
        console.log('no match');
      }
    });
  }
};
```

then I'm trying to use {filterMap} in the scrollview.

Am I breaking scope?

Comment: Is the error coming from the filter() or map()?

Comment: the map(), filter seems to be fine

Comment: did you solve your problem?